# How can I dynamically detect links/phone numbers/addresses etc in a SwiftUI Text

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, datadetectortypes

I am using SwiftUI and would like to have something similar to .dataDetectorTypes in a UITextView to dynamically display content and allow links or phone numbers or addresses to be clickable in a SwiftUI Text or TextEditor.

As this will be for a chat app the content is dynamic and so just using .onTap won't work.  Ideally I would like to use something like textView.dataDetectorTypes = .all in either a Text or TextEditor in SwiftUI but it seems that is not available.

Currently I'm using a UITextView Representable but having all sorts of issues there with dynamic height adjustment and scroll performance so hoping to find a SwiftUI way of doing this without UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: Since you can use `AttributedString` in IOS15, I guess you could use `NSDataDetector` on text, iterate over the links found, and construct an `AttributedString` from that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (as of the current version of swiftUI) you will need to continue to use `UITextView` for having a dynamic height have you looked at [this post](https://lostmoa.com/blog/DynamicHeightForTextFieldInSwiftUI/) it might help with your height issues (maybe)...

Comment: I'm using UITextView via UIViewRepresentable, I have a binding the UITextView modifies view textView.contentSize.height and the cell views in a LazyVStack do change height, however the text inside the UITextView sometime does not show up.